# Use uid or token for storing facebook session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth

Hey I was watching the following railscast on omniauth and was wondering if using the `uid` is the right way to store the session. Wouldn't it be more secure to store the credentials token instead?

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

I have the following schema and want to be able to create new users from facebook. Any ideas on how to do this properly?

```
        Column         |            Type             |                     Modifiers                      
------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name             | character varying(255)      | 
 last_name              | character varying(255)      | 
 email                  | character varying(255)      | 
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone | not null
 password_digest        | character varying(255)      | 
 remember_token         | character varying(255)      | 
 admin                  | boolean                     | default false
 password_reset_token   | character varying(255)      | 
 password_reset_sent_at | timestamp without time zone |
```

Answer (score 0):

Realistically you will need both. The token will change with time and you are likely to need a way to store/create your own data about the user.

Answer (score 0):

The unique identifier provided by facebook can be dynamic and on/off as stated by pork.

I have been using social logins for several projects now and I must say that using the social login in combination with devise never let me down.

To make sure you do not create a new record when the uid for whatever reason changed or isn't present anymore just make it check on the returned auth_info without the uid.

good luck